# Merge specific files with magit

Tags: magit, git, version-control

Is there a way to merge single files in magit like you would do from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355990/3524689) or something equivalent. Namely:

```
$ git checkout source_branch -- <paths>...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in many answers to the question you have linked to and even more so in comments on those answers, `git checkout source_branch -- <paths>...` does not perform a merge.

Never-the-less there are of course situations when you want to do that - just don't call it a "merge". It would be much more appropriate to talk about "putting a file in the worktree into its state as per a certain commit".

You can do that with `M-x magit-file-checkout`.

However you might actually be interested in only bringing in the *changes* (not final state) introduced by a certain commit to a certain file. To do that show the diff for that commit, then move to the file's heading in the diff and press <kbd>a</kbd>. That just applies just the changes that were introduced in that particular commit. You can also do that on the hunk and line level.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `M-x magit-file-checkout`

This will allow you to pull in the changes from a specific file at a specific revision (you'll be prompted for those) into your working tree.

Comment: @Drew I added a bit more detail to the answer, hope that clarifies it